# How to add a vertical bar on a panel?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, primeng

I'm simply trying to add a vertical bar that can go from top to bottom on the **right side** of my panel. I would prefer to have a class instead of an in-line css style. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing,  please? Thanks a lot in advance!

**NOTE:**

- I want a div inside my p-panel to make the vertical bar

**Here's my code:**

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dDfDdOgg7znAjqS9dSu4?p=preview)

```
<p-panel>
 <p-header>
    Title
</p-header>

  <textarea [rows]="5" [cols]="30" pInputTextarea autoResize="autoResize"></textarea>
  <div class = "my-class"></div>

</p-panel>
```

**Here's a pic of what I want:**

[image]

Comment: Would a border work> https://plnkr.co/edit/rCy90JTxXFOoWSI9GcDH?p=preview

Comment: No, I would rather want to have a div inside my panel and not a class at the p-panel level. Because I'll be using it as a splitter in the future.

Comment: The question needs to be improved as comments done by OP raises some contradictions, Question lacks enough information needed to visualize the scenerio. it does not answer the basic queries like, will the splitter be a resizable or not? if not what is the splitter needed for? will there be anything on the other side of the splitter? If nothing will be on the other side of the splitter then why not just use a styled border?

Comment: @MunimMunna maybe don't use the "splitter" word. I just want a vertical bar on the right side of the panel (the vertical bar needs to be inside the panel). That is all, plain and simple.

Comment: Do you want to make it inside the Title div?

Comment: The vertical bar should look like the picture I posted, and its div should be inside the p-panel tag. Thanks

Comment: @progx Well, do you want to add items inside of it or just like the picture above?

Comment: @Liam just like the picture above

Comment: @progx Ok check out my answer

Comment: @Liam I need to add a custom class in my HTML code like class = ''my-class'. That's the way I want to create my vertical bar because I will be using that class later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/K3SQnzRBjuZMRH0P61u3?p=preview

```
.ui-panel {
  position: relative !important;
}

.my-box {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 3px; 
  top: 3px; 
  bottom: 3px; 
  width: 40px; 
  background: red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You bet! Can you also award your bounty? :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox layout.

Override `ui-panel-content` class to use flex properties :

```
.ui-panel-content {
  padding: 0 !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; // for the textarea to be on the left and the border on the right
}
```

Here is your panel HTML content :

```
<div class="panelContent">
      <textarea [rows]="5" [cols]="30" pInputTextarea autoResize="autoResize"></textarea>
    </div>

<div class="panelBorder"></div>
```

and its relevant CSS :

```
.panelContent {
  padding:5px;
}

.panelBorder {
  background: red; 
  width: 4px;
}
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q9pOK8EAjVDIeQG98Ub4?p=preview)

Comment: You are close, but I would like the vertical bar to start from the panel header all the way down to the bottom just like I have it on my picture.

Comment: is there anyway to not wrap it into a main div like you have it "id="mainPanel" ?

Comment: If you absolutely want a div, I don't think so.

Answer (score -1):

how about just putting in a div, give it some width and some height (what ever you like), give it position:absolute; then right:0; and position:fixed?

```
example{
background-color:red;
width:5%;
height:100%;
right:0%;
position:absolute;
position:fixed;
}
```

or maybe the code is too simple? but here's a suggestion.